# Function Running Sync When VS Says it should be running async

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Why Does B Run  Sync? Vs Says ."Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed." ;

```
A) Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Funcation(1, 1)); //Runs Async

B) Funcation(1, 1); // Says it runs async in vs, but really runs sync.
C)  var handleOne = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Funcation(1, 1);
        }); // Runs Async
D) await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Funcation(1, 1)); //awaits correctly
E) await Funcation(1, 1); //awaits correctly


 static private async Task<int> Funcation(int x, int y)
 {
     Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Funcation` is using `async` keyword but does not `await` for anything in it's body so it will always run synchronously. also `Function` does not even compile.

**A)**

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Funcation(1, 1)); //Runs Async
```

here you create a thread and on that thread you call `Function` so it is asynchrounsly because it is running on another thread.

**B)**

```
Funcation(1, 1);
```

`Function` is marked `async` but not `await`ed where it is invoked. In this case the compiler does not check whether `Function` is using `await` in it's body or not (it has already told you that on your function declaration). It just check that you are invoking an asynchronous  method without awaiting it.

**C)**

```
var handleOne = Task.Run(() => { Funcation(1, 1); }); // Runs Async
```

I'm not really sure on this one, if someone knows what happens here please help.

**D)**

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Funcation(1, 1)); //awaits correctly
```

same as **A** but you await the created task and everything is OK. also it is a very bad idea to create a task to run an asynchronous operation.

**E)**

```
await Funcation(1, 1); //awaits correctly
```

do we really except something else happens? It's really the way you should use `async` and `await`.

Comment: B is still where i am confused when i run the code it seems B as it is, Does not Run async. It appears it runs sync, as it blocks the current thread from moving forward. Nothing runs after B is called intill B is done. With B as it is, is it running async or sync?

Comment: compiler told you on function declaration that your async method does not await anything so it will be run synchronously, and when you call it like **B** then it will run synchronously

Comment: "execution of the current method continues before the call is completed" I thought this meant that the call is async, as the current method will continue. K So I am misunderstanding what vs is telling me. I think i got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is using `Wait`, which is *blocking*.  Use `await` instead.  Also, you defined the task as a `Task<int>`, but didn't return any result - which won't compile.  It should be something like this:

```
static private async Task<int> Funcation(int x, int y)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    return x + y; // some int result
}
```

Use your code "E" to invoke.  The other invocations are all incorrect.

Also, if your code really doesn't need the delay, then this would not be a good use case for async.  Async operations should be doing things that are long-running or IO bound.  If your code is just performing simple arithmetic, then just make it a traditional synchronous method.